# Проверочная система выдает ошибку "Переменная friend_string должна быть строкой."

Tags: python

У меня есть такой код:

```
print("Привет, я Анфиса!")
friends = ['Серёга', 'Соня', 'Дима', 'Алина', 'Егор']
friends_string = friends
print('Твои друзья: ' + ', '.join(friends))
```

При попытке запуска выдает ошибку:

> Переменная `friend_string` должна быть строкой.

Вопрос: как мне получить вывод вида

> Привет, я Анфиса!
>
> Твои друзья: Серёга, Соня, Дима, Алина, Егор

Ниже скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переменная `friends_string` должна быть строкой.

Comment: Некогда не делай так лучше используй format это не создаёт новые объекты

Comment: Вывод на скриншоте соответствует тому, что требуется в вопросе. Непонятно в чем проблема.

Comment: Поменял причину закрытия, было - "задано не на русском языке".

Answer (score 5):

Как и написано в тексте ошибки, в переменной `friends_string` должна быть строка, а у вас там список, поэтому:

```
print("Привет, я Анфиса!")
friends = ['Серёга', 'Соня', 'Дима', 'Алина', 'Егор']
friends_string = ', '.join(friends)
print('Твои друзья: ' + friends_string)
```